# How join two collections in MongoDB using node js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have searched for join two collection in MongoDB. I found populate. But it is not working for my scenario. I am using mongoose in node js. My schema are like below.

```
const CoordinateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    activationId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Activation'
    },
    mac: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
        required: true,
        set: toLower
    },
    t: { type: Date },
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
        required: true,
        //unique: true,
        set: toLower
    },
    mac: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        set: toLower,
        index: true
    },
    dob: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Date,
    },
    gender: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String, set: toLower },
    activations: [{
        activationId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Activation'
        },
        userType: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String, set: toLower },
        _id: false
    }]
}
```

i have thousands of records for single activation in coordinates collection.

My query query requires to filter distinct mac from coordinates collection which matches userType in user collection.

If i use populate method & then apply filter on that it won't restrict fetching record count because of it query is taking so much time because it will return thousands of records.

I want to fetch only coordinates which match userType in user collection.

So far i haven't found any efficient method to join two collection & apply where condition on it.

I want to know efficient method to join two  collection in mongodb & apply where condition on both collections.

Comment: sounds like `$lookup` aggregation could be the solution to this. did you try?

Comment: $lookup performs as left outer join. which won't restrict records of  first collection. i want something to perform as inner join.

Comment: You can combine `$unwind` and `$lookup` to restrict records from the first collection. Or change your schema and embed the required field

Comment: can you provide example code? SQL query will be like this `SELECT mac from coordinates inner join users inner join on coordinates.mac=users.mac where coordinates.activationId="..." and users.activation.userType="..."`